# WPF copy blend Regular Polygon into application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a ellipse with a triangle in Blend 2012. I went to copy the xaml into my WPF application. However I get the error message "The name RegularPolygon does not exist in the namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing. What is missing?

```
   <Application x:Class="WpfSimulator.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" 
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

 <ed:RegularPolygon HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" InnerRadius="1" Margin="29,14,0,0" PointCount="3" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="37" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <ed:RegularPolygon.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90.492"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </ed:RegularPolygon.RenderTransform>
        <ed:RegularPolygon.Fill>
            <RadialGradientBrush RadiusY="1.241" RadiusX="0.611">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF1F1FD8"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </ed:RegularPolygon.Fill>
    </ed:RegularPolygon>
```

Comment: Do you have the [Expression Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801) installed?

Comment: yes when I go to install that sdk I get an error message saying "A newer version of Microsoft Expression Blend SDK for .NET 4 is already installed."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add reference to the assembly `Microsoft.Expression.Drawing`. 
Like this:
[image]